# Listening to multiple Observables in a Stream

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I really can't get my head around.
I have a container which is listening to a dialog. The dialog can emit different actions. Based on the emitted action I want to call some additional logic.
I really want to archive this without nested subscriptions or if statements. How can I do this?
Here is what I've tried:

```
    this.commonProducts$
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        map(commonProducts => (this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddProductDialogComponent, { data: commonProducts }))),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.dialogRef.actions.pull(DialogProductAddActions.frequency).pipe(
            map(newProduct => {
              // do some actions
            })
          );
        }),
        switchMap(() => {
          return this.dialogRef.actions.pull(DialogProductAddActions.schedule).pipe(
            map(newProduct => {
              // do other action
            })
          );
        })
      )
      .subscribe(() => this.dialogRef.close());
```

But only the first switchmap is working.

Comment: Your `map()` doesn't really make sense to me. `map()` is a transformation function. It defines how a stream is transformed by mapping the stream's individual elements. You're not transforming `commonProducts` meaningfully since you never use your stream values afterwards. Probably you should be using `tap()` instead.

Comment: You have two `switchMap()`'s that are identical, neither of which use the input they're given. What you're essentially saying is "I don't care what the input is, I want to switch into this new stream I'm defining." That's all fine and well, essentially the stream is just acting to link asynchronous code together sequentially. What I'm confused about is why you're taking the output of `dialogRef.actions.pull()` and switching that into `dialogRef.actions.pull()` again. What are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: I don't want so switch again. I want to listen to the dialog action and  dependent on the emitted action I want to execute one of the two switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [iif](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif) operator in rxjs and modify the code as below

```
const observable1$ = this.dialogRef.actions.pull(DialogProductAddActions.frequency).pipe(
        map(newProduct => {
          // do some actions
        })
      );
const observable2$ = return this.dialogRef.actions.pull(DialogProductAddActions.schedule).pipe(
        map(newProduct => {
          // do other action
        })
      );

 this.commonProducts$
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    map(commonProducts => (this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddProductDialogComponent, { data: commonProducts }))),
    switchMap(() => iif(() => condition, observable1$, observable2$))
)
```